# Parse order and/or single/double quote issue with Calendar events and Google Map Info Window

Tags: playa, parse-order, google-maps-for-ee, calendar

I am utilizing a combination of Solspace 'Calendar', 'Playa', and 'Google Maps for ExpressionEngine'. I'm having a strange issue where the dates aren't showing up correctly in my infowindows on the Google Map, but they show up fine using the same code outside of the infowindow.

So, I have a 'Location' channel, and an 'Event' channel. The Event channel is associated with the Calendar module, and uses a Playa single relationship field to relate it to a Location.

I am adding markers to the map for every 'Location', and for each marker, I'm populating the infowindow with the Location details. this includes using the Playa:Parents method to show all of the events that are at that location.

I copied the code from the Solspace Calendar demo template for a single event to show the event date, because it had all the conditionals all worked out to deal with single day or multi-day events well.

My problem is that in the infowindow, it's only showing the 'From' date, and not the 'To' part of the date string. It shows it correctly when I output it outside of the map, though. Here is the code that is outputting the date information.

```
    {exp:calendar:events}
    <b>From:</b> {event_first_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
    {if event_never_ends}
        (never ends)
    {if:else}
        {if "{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}" != "{event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}"} <b>to:</b>
            {if "{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d"}" != "{event_last_date format="%Y%m%d"}"}
                {event_last_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
            {if:else}
                {event_last_date format="%g:%i%a"}
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/if}
    <a href="{path=find-music/event/{url_title}}">{title}</a>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

But this is how it outputs, in the infowindow, and outside of the map.

(crap, I don't have enough 'reputation' to post the image here, but it's here: http://paleosun.com/misc/stackexchange-map-calendar-question.jpg)

Notice, the section below the map has the "to" date. Same code is used to output it.

I have determined that something is going wrong with the quotes in the event date formatting tags. The `{if "{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}" != "{event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}"}` part is never resolving to 'true' like it should. In fact, If I just try to output `{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}` in the infowindow part, nothing show up. However, if I use double quotes and output `{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d%g%i%a"}` it DOES work. The problem is, I cannot use that fix in the conditional, because double quotes are already being used around the output of that tag...

Any ideas why? Or what I can do as a work-around?

Here is all of my relevant template code:

```
{exp:gmap:init
    id="mainmap"
    class="gmap"
    style="height:600px;width:100%; border: 1px solid green;"
    center="United States"
    zoom="4"
}

<div id="location-container">
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="location"
        disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields"
        limit="9999"
        }

        {if loc_show_on_map == 'yes'}

            {exp:gmap:marker
                id="mainmap"
                latitude="{loc_latitude}"
                longitude="{loc_longitude}"
                geocode="false"
                clustering="true"
                infobox="true"
                show_one_window="true"
                class="ui-infobox-dark ui-infobox"
                offsetY="-45"
                offsetX="15"
                icon="{categories limit='1'}{category_image}{/categories}"
                }

                <div style="width: 400px;" class="clearfix">
                    <h3><a href="{path=find-music/location/{url_title}}">{title}</a></h3>

                    <ul>
                        {categories}
                            <li>{category_name}</li>
                        {/categories}
                    </ul>

                    {if loc_image}<img src="{loc_image}" alt="{title} image" width="200" class="right" />{/if}
                    {loc_contact_first_name} {loc_contact_last_name}<br />
                    {loc_street_address} {if loc_address_details}{loc_address_details}{/if}<br />
                    {loc_city_town}, {loc_state} {loc_zip_code}<br />


                    <ul>
                    {exp:playa:parents channel="calendar_events"}
                        <li>
                            {exp:calendar:events}
                                <b>From:</b> {event_first_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}

                        <br />From:{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}
                        <br />To: {event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}!
                        Yes
                                {if event_never_ends}
                                    (never ends)
                                {if:else}
                                    {if "{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}" != "{event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}"} <b>to:</b>
                                        {if "{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d"}" != "{event_last_date format="%Y%m%d"}"}
                                            {event_last_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
                                        {if:else}
                                            {event_last_date format="%g:%i%a"}
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                {/if}
                                <a href="{path=find-music/event/{url_title}}">{title}</a>
                            {/exp:calendar:events}
                        </li>
                    {/exp:playa:parents}
                    </ul>
                </div>

            {/exp:gmap:marker}

            {!--
                custom javascript to add attributes to the markers
                for location type and music styles, so we can filter
                based on that
            --}
            <script type="text/javascript">
                if(typeof newMarker!='undefined'){
                    newMarker.entry_id = {entry_id};
                    newMarker.music_styles = [];
                    {exp:playa:children field="loc_music_styles"}
                        newMarker.music_styles.push({entry_id});
                    {/exp:playa:children}

                    newMarker.location_types = [];
                    {categories}
                        newMarker.location_types.push({category_id});
                    {/categories}
                }
            </script>
        {/if}

        <div id="location-{entry_id}"  class="location-entry clearfix">
            <h3><a href="{path=find-music/location/{url_title}}">{title}</a></h3>
            {if loc_image}<img src="{loc_image}" alt="{title} image" width="200" class="right" />{/if}
            {loc_contact_first_name} {loc_contact_last_name}<br />
            {loc_street_address} {if loc_address_details}{loc_address_details}{/if}<br />
            {loc_city_town}, {loc_state} {loc_zip_code}<br />

            <ul>
            {exp:playa:parents channel="calendar_events"}
                <li>
                    {exp:calendar:events}
                        <b>From:</b> {event_first_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
                        {if event_never_ends}
                            (never ends)
                        {if:else}
                            {if "{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}" != "{event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}"} <b>to:</b>
                                {if "{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d"}" != "{event_last_date format="%Y%m%d"}"}
                                    {event_last_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
                                {if:else}
                                    {event_last_date format="%g:%i%a"}
                                {/if}
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                        <a href="{path=find-music/event/{url_title}}">{title}</a>
                    {/exp:calendar:events}
                </li>
            {/exp:playa:parents}
            </ul>
            <hr />
        </div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div> <!-- /#location-container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of a workaround, but that is definitely a parse order issue. Given this is a very unique scenario, it would be rather difficult to duplicate without getting access to your EE install.

Email support@objectivehtml.com and I can try to help you find a workaround. I am not sure who this support requests belongs to, me (Objective HTML), P&T, or Solspace but I can try to help you. :)

Comment: Justin, I think I can help PaleoSun, but I don't understand enough about your addon. Please, may I put the content of gmap:marker inside an embed?

Answer (score 0):

I never used GoogleMpas for EECMS, but let's try something.

I already had some problems to solve because of nested `exp:channel:entries` and `exp:channel:events`.

So, let's first move them to an embed, but trying to reduce the number of times the modules are parsed and improve the performance.

```
{embed="events/.mapmarkers" event_ids="{exp:playa:parents channel='calendar_events' backspace='1'}{entry_id}|{/exp:playa:parents}"}
```

[The default format of the variables](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#event_start_date) of `exp:channel:events` is already YYYYMMDD. So you don't need to format some of your conditionals.

```
{if "{event_first_date}" != "{event_last_date}"}
```

Other conditionals, can have the double and single quotation marks replaced and the '%a' can be removed if you use ['%H'](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html#date-formatting-codes).

```
{if '{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}' != '{event_last_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}' }
```

Your embed will look like this:

```
{if embed:event_ids !== ""}
    <ul>
    {exp:calendar:events parse="inward" event_id="{embed:event_ids}"}
        <li>
        <b>From:</b> {event_first_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}

        <br />From:{event_first_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}
        <br />To: {event_last_date format='%Y%m%d%g%i%a'}!
        Yes
            {if event_never_ends}
                (never ends)
            {if:else}
                {if '{event_first_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}' != '{event_last_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}' } <b>to:</b>
                    {if "{event_first_date}" != "{event_last_date}"}
                        {event_last_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}
                    {if:else}
                        {event_last_date format="%g:%i%a"}
                    {/if}
                {/if}
            {/if}
            <a href="{path=find-music/event/{url_title}}">{title}</a>
        </li>
    {/exp:calendar:events}
    </ul>
{/if}
```

Because you're calling this twice on your template, I strongly suggest you to use [stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) to save the content of the embed.